# QFileDialog getSaveFileName filter only specifc drive

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qfiledialog

I'm using pyqt and I just made a Qfiledialog to save a PDF that my program produced, like this:

```
QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "", ".pdf")
```

But the file must be saved at "P:\", in any folder, but have to be "P:".
How can I do that?

Comment: Why `P:\`? What if there's no such drive?

Comment: This is a remote app. If c: is shown, they will save at the server, and P: its a mapped network folder that everyone have access. And belive me, people get confused about local PC, network and remote PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `directoryEntered` and `fileSelected` signals instead of modal `getSaveFileName`. Some pseudo code:

```
self.dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
self.dialog.directoryEntered.connect(self.checkDir)
self.dialog.fileSelected.connect(self.saveFile)
self.dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
self.dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)
self.dialog.setDirectory("P:")
self.dialog.show()
....
def checkDir(self, directory):
    if not (directory.startsWith("P:")):
        self.dialog.setDirectory("P:")

def saveFile(self, fileName):
    directory = QtCore.QFileInfo(fileName).canonicalPath()
```

Comment: Thank you! But I stil have two questions. What I'm doing wrong and what should I do in saveFile? How I get the file name and folder? 
     def gera_pdf(self): 
        dia = QtGui.QFileDialog()
        dia.directoryEntered.connect(self.checkDir)
        dia.fileSelected.connect(self.saveFile)
        dia.setDirectory("P:")
        dia.show()
        
    def checkDir(self, directory):
        if not (directory.startsWith("P:")):
            QtGui.QFileDialog.setDirectory("P:")
   def saveFile(self):
        1==1
           PASTED HERE TOO: http://pastebin.com/Rg03xJB5

Comment: Almost there! TypeError: QDir.absoluteFilePath(QString): not enough arguments. What should be the argument?

Comment: My bad. Use `QFileInfo.canonicalPath()`.